# Spatie Media Library Generating Thumbnail from base64string

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, media-library, laravel-medialibrary

i've practiced as it is in the spatie media library v8 documentation, but it doesn't work when i use base64 files.

In Controller:

```
$mediaFile = request('image');
$filename = 'abcd.jpeg';

$product = Product::find($id);
$product->addMediaFromBase64($mediaFile)
        ->usingFileName($filename)
        ->toMediaCollection('product', 's3');
```

In Model:

```
public $registerMediaConversionsUsingModelInstance = true;

public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
{
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
              ->width(320)
              ->height(200)
              ->performOnCollections('product');
}
```

Error:

> Typed property Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\Conversion::$conversionFileNamer must be an instance of Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\ConversionFileNamer, Laravel\Lumen\Application used

If I upload an image without a thumbnail (registerMediaConversions) it works.

Comment: use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia; and in your class add use InteractsWithMedia;

Comment: I have used it.

Comment: I've found the problem, the image I'm using the extension is png should be jpeg. thanks